# Api Upsert by one of two admins overwrites the other admin's record instead of creating a duplicate

Tags: rest-api, upsert, admin

I have an org with two admins: AdminA and AdminB.

1. AdminA upserts a record with an external ID - this creates a new
   record
2. AdminB upserts the same record with the same external ID.

I would expect this to create a new record for AdminB since he's a different user. However, the original record created by AdminB is now updated, showing AdminA as  the owner but AdminB as the modifier.

Is there a way to ensure that a new record is created even if the user is an Admin, if there is no record owned by him with the same external ID?

Comment: If you're using the same External ID, surely it's the same record and thus the point of an upsert remains - update it if it exists, insert it if it doesn't.  Ownership doesn't come into the equation

Comment: I hear you. Let me clarify further: 

The external ID, is supposed to uniquely identify a record in the originating system. Let's say we're talking about Company records, imported to Salesforce as Accounts. We have two users, each of whom want to import their own copy of the Company, and then later be able to modify it. If the External ID used is the ID of the Company record in the originating system it will be identical for both users and and they will share the same record instead of each having his own copy.

Comment: Sounds like the External ID is not being *actively* used as one in this scenario and could just be used as a reference for the user only, i.e., clear the external ID flag to prevent the upsert from attempting to match on it.  That way, matching would be done on SFDC record ID only, and not finding a match, would insert it.

Comment: Thanks! If I don't uncheck the external Id field (or if someone adds their own external id field) can I still upsert matching the SFDC record Id?

Comment: I think it depends on your API Call - using Data Loader as an example of something that consumes the API in this way, if you don't specify the external ID field in the CSV you're uploading (or wilfully choose not to map it), it will quite happily ignore it ;-)